# Insert the selected multiple values in PHP to another table

Tags: php, mysql

`$SelectSql = "SELECT Id FROM Item WHERE ProductId = 2 LIMIT 3";`

I have the above query in a PHP page which results in the output as follows:

```
Id
5
6
7
```

Now I need to insert these records into another table like below

```
Insert into table2 (Id,name) values(5,a), values(6,a), values (7,a)
```

But what I tried programmatically is

```
$SelectSql = "SELECT Id FROM Item WHERE ProductId = 2 LIMIT '$PostQuantity'";
$ItemResult2 = $dbcon->query($SelectSql);
if ($ItemResult2->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $ItemResult2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["Id"];
        $Insertsql = "INSERT INTO ItemMovement (CustomerId,ItemId,DeliveryDate,ReturnDate) VALUES('$CustomerId','$id','2015-07-15','2017-11-15')";
        mysqli_query($dbcon, $Insertsql);
            // echo $Advance;
    }
}
```

Which doesn't work. What are the other methods to Insert the selected values?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements, to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Actually i have did it on purpose for posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this single query.i think its enough.

```
INSERT INTO ItemMovement (CustomerId,ItemId,DeliveryDate,ReturnDate)

        SELECT '$CustomerId',Id,'2015-07-15','2017-11-15' FROM  Item WHERE ProductId = 2 LIMIT 3
```

Comment: $CustomerId and the two dates are not in Item table.

Comment: i put it as value directly ,its surrounded with single quotes

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
$CustomerId = 10; // test case.
```

it will update your and put date static for your condition or you can use now () also but one important thing `ItemMovement`  this table need `auto increment` field . and if your select table have no filed which insert table need then use null or static value , suppose your customerId = 10; then

```
INSERT INTO `ItemMovement` (`CustomerId`,`ItemId`,`DeliveryDate`,`ReturnDate`)
        SELECT 10,Id,'2015-07-15','2017-11-15' FROM  Item WHERE ProductId = 2 LIMIT 3;
```

just replace above query

```
10
```

to

```
'$CustomerId'
```

this is general format

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

for more information

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html